# What happens to guest accounts?

Tags: discussion

I posted as a guest, and I was wondering, do these guest accounts get deleted after a day? Or does it just stay there until you delete it yourself?

Answer (score 3):

Guest accounts are just like any other account, they stay until you delete it yourself, or merge it into another account. The main disadvantage of a guest account is that it is [only associated to you by a temporary cookie](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44562/133427). As you don't have an actual login and password, there's no way to log into it from another PC or device, and if the cookie expires then there's no way to access that account again.

If you have an existing guest account that you've used to post a question or answer and you'd like it merged into your [new registered account](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/why-register), see this help page: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Thanks for the information, but how do I delete my guest account? I went to edit my information, but I can't find the way to delete it. Edit: Do you have to change your display name to 'please delete me' or something like that?

Comment: Which account is your guest account?

Comment: This one actually.

Comment: I can delete the account for you. Please confirm that you want the account deleted.

Comment: And how do I do that? o.o

Comment: Just acknowledge in a comment here that you want it deleted :)

Comment: Umm.. I'd like for this account to be deleted haha

Comment: Is it deleted now? Or do I have to clear cookies as well?

Comment: It is scheduled to be deleted. It will be deleted in 24 hours.